# How do I implement weight noise in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What is the best way to implement weight noise in Tensorflow? Should I extract all the weights and apply noise? Or should I apply noise to the gradients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weight noise and gradient noise are not the same.

There is a weight noise with following weight update:

[image]

And gradient noise (sometimes called Langevin noise) that applies gradients as following:

[image]

The latter is the update of Stochastic Gradient Langevin Dynamics optimizer.

In any case, it is pretty straighforward to implement both in tensorflow.

```
# Assuming you defined a graph and loss function `loss` and noise
# is drawn from normal distribution

# Weight noise:
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
train_ops = [tf.assign(v, 
                       v - lr*g + tf.random_normal(v.shape, stddev=0.1))
             for g, v in grads_and_vars]
train_op = tf.group(train_ops)

# Langevin noise:
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
train_ops = [tf.assign(v, 
                       v - lr*g - tf.sqrt(lr*T)*tf.random_normal(v.shape, stddev=1))
             for g, v in grads_and_vars]
train_op = tf.group(train_ops)
```